# Identify File Growth Events

Tags: sql-server, datafile

I'm discovering a number of DBs in my portfolio that have been created with default autogrow settings (either 1 MB or 10% increments) that have expanded for an extended period of time. If I wanted to get a gauge of the amount of external fragmentation for each of the DB files, can I get from metadata how many times a DB file has been modified in size (either by autogrow or manually)? To clarify, can I get from metadata the history of DB file modifications for the life of the DB, not just since instance restart?

Comment: Unless they have also been shrunk at some point this should be a simple calculation from initial size to current size based on the auto grow setting?

Comment: If it was only modified by autogrow, I would agree but I've seen manual modifications done which may be outside autogrow settings.

Answer (score 20):

You can get autogrowth events information from the default trace if it is enabled:

```
select distinct
    ei.eventid,
    e.name
from sys.fn_trace_geteventinfo(1) ei
inner join sys.trace_events e
on e.trace_event_id = ei.eventid
where name like '%grow%';
```

You can see from this that the default trace does have the **Data File Auto Grow** and **Log File Auto Grow** events capture.  To see if you have the default trace enabled on that instance, you can do the following:

```
exec sp_configure 'default trace enabled';
go
```

*Note: this is an advanced configuration option, so `show advanced options` would have to get set to 1 to view this configuration option through `sp_configure`.  Also, [these two events will not be triggered if the file grew manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187491%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).*

Here is a quick sample query to get these events:

```
select
    te.name as event_name,
    tr.DatabaseName,
    tr.FileName,
    tr.StartTime,
    tr.EndTime
from sys.fn_trace_gettable('<Trace Path>', 0) tr
inner join sys.trace_events te
on tr.EventClass = te.trace_event_id
where tr.EventClass in (92, 93)
order by EndTime;
```

And you can get `<Trace Path>` from the system function `sys.fn_trace_getinfo`:

```
select *
from sys.fn_trace_getinfo(1);
```

Comment: This is good information, just bear in mind that some of those events could well have expired from the default trace.

Comment: Absolutely, but I believe it's the only out-of-the-box monitoring that the OP will get on this with actually doing the proper auditing.